# Error: Nothing to do while installing percona server on centos 7?

Tags: centos7, percona

Can't install percona on centos 7

```
yum install http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/redhat/0.1-3/percona-release-0.1-3.noarch.rpm
```

Output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
percona-release-0.1-3.noarch.rpm                                                                                  | 149 kB  00:00:00
Cannot open: http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/redhat/0.1-3/percona-release-0.1-3.noarch.rpm. Skipping.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I'm using this tutorial:

https://elearning.wsldp.com/pcmagazine/install-percona-server-centos-7/

https://docs.percona.com/percona-server/5.7/installation/yum_repo.html#installing-from-the-percona-yum-repository

Percona isn't installed when I do this:

```
systemctl status mysql
```

Output:

```
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
```

How do I fix this error?

Update:

Fixed:

```
yum install https://repo.percona.com/testing/centos/7/RPMS/x86_64/Percona-Server-55-debuginfo-5.5.59-rel38.11.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: RPM was not available on used url, Systemctl will be used once service/unit is available but as package is not installed unit file also not available. Please update your question if still facing issue.

Comment: Please don't provide the solution in the question, instead post an answer and accept it. Otherwise the question will stay as unsolved in the system forever.

Answer (score 0):

The link in this tutorial are outdated. From the [official installation instructions](https://docs.percona.com/percona-server/5.7/installation/yum_repo.html#installing-from-the-percona-yum-repository):

> Install the Percona yum repository by running the following command as a root user or with sudo:
>
> ```
> $ sudo yum install https://repo.percona.com/yum/percona-release-latest.noarch.rpm
> ```
>
> Enable the Percona Server 5.7 repository:
>
> ```
> $ sudo percona-release setup ps57
> ```

Then continue with installing the server.

The package `Server-55-debuginfo-5.5.59` you've installed is a) an outdated version and b) a debugging version that will use more resources as the regular version.